# Initialization error while opening migration assistance for MySQL

Tags: sql, mysql

I am trying to migrate my MySQL database to SQL Server. I have already installed the ODBC driver and SSMA for MySQL. However I got an initialization error when trying to open SSMA.

> Cannot start because of an initialization error

Try to restart the application. If this problem remains, contact support group (please provide a log file).

Unexpected error.

```
Exception: One or more errors occurred.
 site: 
 source: 

InnerException #1: The type initializer for 'Microsoft.SSMA.Framework.Generic.AbstractTelemetryProvider.Containers.TelemetryEventData' threw an exception.
 site: Void .ctor(Microsoft.SSMA.Framework.Generic.AbstractTelemetryProvider.Enums.TelemetryOperationType, System.Guid)
 source: Microsoft.SSMA.Framework.Generic.AbstractTelemetryProvider
   at Microsoft.SSMA.Framework.Generic.AbstractTelemetryProvider.Containers.TelemetryEventData..ctor(TelemetryOperationType operationType, Guid activityId)
   at Microsoft.SSMA.Framework.Generic.AbstractTelemetryProvider.Recorders.Abstraction.TelemetryEventRecorder.AddEvent(TelemetryOperationType eventType)
   at Microsoft.SSMA.Framework.Generic.AbstractTelemetryProvider.Recorders.TelemetryApplicationEventRecorder.WriteSetup(String osName, String productName, Boolean isInternal)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.SSMA.GUI.Product.SourceToTarget.Startup.GuiBootstrap`1.<InitializeAsync>d__11.MoveNext()
InnerException #2: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
 site: System.String GetMachineId()
 source: Microsoft.SSMA.Framework.Generic.AbstractTelemetryProvider
   at Microsoft.SSMA.Framework.Generic.AbstractTelemetryProvider.Containers.TelemetryEventData.GetMachineId()
   at Microsoft.SSMA.Framework.Generic.AbstractTelemetryProvider.Containers.TelemetryEventData..cctor()
```

I could not find the solution and I really hope anyone could help me with this issue.